# Can't install discord.js from npm ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, npm

The error I'm getting:

[image: the error]

My internet connection is fine, and I have the firewall turned off, and I'm not using ipv6. I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when your device cannot connect to registry.npmjs.org

You can try pinging using the following command; `$ ping registry.npmjs.org`. If it does not ping it means your device cannot connect. You can check the following;

1. Check your connection, are you sure you have a connection to the internet?
2. Check your proxy
3. Check your firewall, you can try disabling it

You can also see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911529/how-to-fix-npm-installation-issue) for similar answers

Comment: The firewall is off, and the internet is good. How do i fix the proxy?

Comment: I'm not an expert on proxies, you're probably better off just searching it on google.